# how to add records to has_many :through association in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have these models

```
class EventGroups < ActiveRecord::Base      
  has_many  :festival_venues
  has_many  :venues, :through => :festival_venues    
end

class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many  :festival_venues
  has_many  :event_groups, :through => :festival_venues 
end

class FestivalVenue < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :event_group
  belongs_to :venue
end
```

1. Now I want to create a **Venue** via **Eventgroups**, and record in the **FestivalVenue** should be created as well.
2. When i delete **Eventgroups** related record in **Venue** and 
   **FestivalVenue** should be deleted as well.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class EventGroup < ActiveRecord::Base      
  has_many  :festival_venues, dependent: :destroy
  has_many  :venues, :through => :festival_venues, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many  :festival_venues
  has_many  :event_groups, :through => :festival_venues  
end

class FestivalVenue < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :event_group
  belongs_to :venue
end
```

Now if you have `event_group` variable bound to `EventGroup` object, you create `Venue` (along with its `FestivalVenue`) with:

```
venue = Venue.create(your_attributes)
event_group.venues << venue
```

Comment: Hi @Marek 
when i do as you answer above,
I get **No association found for name `event_groupss'. Has it been defined yet?** error.

Comment: @Gagan I edited my answer - naming of `EventGroup` model was bad.

Comment: `class EventGroup < ActiveRecord::Base      
  has_many  :festival_venues, dependent: :destroy
  has_many  :venues, :through => :festival_venues, :dependent => :destroy
end`

Here `has_many  :festival_venues, dependent: :destroy` should be 
`has_many  :festival_venues, :dependent=> :destroy`

Answer (score 1):

In your below code, Model class name must be singular. Change class name `EventGroups` to `EventGroup`. Now it will work like a charm.

```
class EventGroup < ActiveRecord::Base      
  has_many  :festival_venues, dependent: :destroy
  has_many  :venues, :through => :festival_venues, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Remaining code is good.

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many  :festival_venues
  has_many  :event_groups, :through => :festival_venues  
end

class FestivalVenue < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :event_group
  belongs_to :venue
end
```

Hope it will help. Thanks